# Rails Bootstrap text inside <div> in a <td> cell not wrapping

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a table where I am listing some hash elements. I would like to have a newline for each item in the list, but if the item is very long and goes past the right edge of the table cell it just disappears off the page. I would like any overflow to wrap. My ERB file looks like this:

```
<table id="audit_trail_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="audit_trail_table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center col-sm-2">Date</th>
    <th class="text-center col-sm-1">User</th>
    <th class="text-center col-sm-1">Item</th>
    <th class="text-center col-sm-1">Action</th>
    <th class="text-center">Changes</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @audits.each do |audit| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= audit.created_at.strftime("%F@%T") %></td>
      <td><%= "#{audit.first_name} #{audit.last_name}" %></td>
      <td><%= audit.auditable_type.titleize %></td>
      <td><%= audit.action.titleize %></td>
      <td>
        <% audit.audited_changes.each do |key,value| %>
          <div><%= "#{key.to_s} : #{value.to_s}" %></div>
      <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the resulting HTML:

```
<table id="audit_trail_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="audit_trail_table_info">
  <thead>
  <tr role="row"><th class="text-center col-sm-2 sorting_desc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="audit_trail_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" aria-label="Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 148px;">Date</th><th class="text-center col-sm-1 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="audit_trail_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="User: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 55px;">User</th><th class="text-center col-sm-1 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="audit_trail_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Item: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 55px;">Item</th><th class="text-center col-sm-1 sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="audit_trail_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 55px;">Action</th><th class="text-center sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="audit_trail_table" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Changes: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 613px;">Changes</th></tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2018-04-27@18:34:44</td>
      <td>Andrew Reilly</td>
      <td>Cleaning</td>
      <td>Update</td>
      <td>
          <div>cleaning_date : [nil, "2018-04-27"]</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2018-04-27@18:34:07</td>
      <td> firefighter</td>
      <td>Cleaning</td>
      <td>Create</td>
      <td>
          <div>notes : testing audits</div>
          <div>ppe_id : 14</div>
          <div>user_id : 5</div>
          <div>advanced : false</div>
          <div>cleaning_date : </div>
          <div>failed_inspection : false</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">2018-04-27@18:33:25</td>
      <td> firefighter</td>
      <td>Inspection</td>
      <td>Create</td>
      <td>
          <div>passed : true</div>
          <div>ppe_id : 16</div>
          <div>results : {"serial"=&gt;"10011", "soiled"=&gt;"pass", "assigned_to"=&gt;"firefighter, ", "contaminated"=&gt;"pass", "inspection_date"=&gt;"2018-04-27", "loss_of_face_opening_adjustment"=&gt;"pass", "reflective_trim_missing_damaged"=&gt;"pass", "shell_physical_damage_seam_integrity"=&gt;"pass", "shell_physical_damage_thermal_damage"=&gt;"pass", "ear_flaps_physical_damage_thermal_damage"=&gt;"pass", "ear_flaps_physical_damage_rips_tears_cuts"=&gt;"pass", "face_shield_goggle_damage_or_missing_components"=&gt;"pass", "suspension_retention_system_damage_or_missing_components"=&gt;"pass", "shell_physical_damage_cracked_crazing_dents_and_abrasions"=&gt;"pass"}</div>
          <div>user_id : 5</div>
          <div>advanced : false</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">2018-04-23@18:06:09</td>
      <td>Andrew Reilly</td>
      <td>Ppe</td>
      <td>Update</td>
      <td>
          <div>user_id : [1, 24]</div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Which produces a table like:

[image]

the `results` row goes off the right side. I can make it scroll sideways but would rather have it wrap the text. Each key/value line is inside it's own div. I have tried adding various versions of `word-wrap` and `overflow-wrap` in various places (the div, the td, etc.)

The reason for using a `<div>` tag inside the `<td>` was it was the only way I could figure out to get each of the key/value pairs onto one line. If there is a better way to the get newlines where I want them and the wrap within the individual item that would work. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Does `table-layout: fixed` help you? https://jsfiddle.net/938L9gwb/1/

Comment: No, nothing changes. I'm using Bootstrap 3.2 so Not sure if that matters. I added the styles from your jsfiddle and it didn't change. I'll mention that  I've read most of the questions like this that I could find on SO and simple fixes like that haven't worked.

Comment: I noticed that if I remove the `<div>` tag and replace it with a `<br>` tag at the end of the line it will at least show the wrapped text on hover in a tooltip box, at least on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was focusing on the wrong thing. The element `white-space:` is probably set to `no-wrap` somewhere in all of my inherited CSS. I simply set the style for the `<td>` thus:

```
<td style="white-space: initial; overflow: auto">
```

and now it's working perfect.